# std::random_shuffle not being seeded

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>


int main() {
    std::vector<short> a(256);
    for (short x = 0; x != 256; ++x) {
        a[x] = x;
    }
    for (auto x : a) { std::cout << x << ' '; } std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::srand(11);

    std::random_shuffle(a.begin(), a.end());
    for (auto x : a) { std::cout << x << ' '; } std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (short x = 0; x != 256; ++x) {
        a[x] = x;
    }
    for (auto x : a) { std::cout << x << ' '; } std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::srand(11);

    std::random_shuffle(a.begin(), a.end());
    for (auto x : a) { std::cout << x << ' '; } std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

So, here is my code. What I expect is, obviously, the same shuffle both times. What I get is, while the shuffles are consistent between launches, they are different and seem to ignore srand! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) what random number generator is used is implementation-defined, it's not guaranteed to use `std::rand`.

You could use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead and pass it a random number generator:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), g);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/UUKET32685)

Answer (score 2):

First note that the version of [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) you use has been deprecated.

Also note (from the previous reference link)

> ...the function `std::rand` is often used.

The keyword here being *often* and not *always*.

If you want to make sure the same sequence is always created, then you should use one of the alternatives, passing either a specific random-number function, or use the `std::shuffle` function passing a generator (from the C++11 "new" [PRNG classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)).